# Error in Form Submit: Form is getting reset instead of submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, form-submit

I am using `jquery.validate.min.js` plugin for form validations and I am doing the execution of the form using Zend Framework

I have a `Add form` and a `Edit form` .

In the add form the validations are working fine and even the form is being saved after the validations are satisfied(or correct). But where as in edit form though the validations of all the fields are correct the form is getting reset when submit is clicked and the edited data is not being saved instead it is getting reset to the previous data.

Where as, when I removed the validations for edit project the edited data is getting submitted and saved.

What could be the error?

Comment: Need more code as currently the error could be anything from a solar-flare to a trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

use `submitHandler`. here is an example

```
            /* Initialize Login Form Validation */
            $('#login-form').validate({
                errorClass: "help-inline",
                errorElement: "span",
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    element.parents(".controls").append(error);
                },
                highlight: function(e) {
                    $(e).closest(".control-group").removeClass("success error").addClass("error");
                },
                success: function(e) {
                    e.addClass("valid").closest(".control-group").removeClass("success error").addClass("success");
                },
                rules: {
                    login_email: {
                        email: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    login_email: {
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                    }
                },
                 submitHandler: function(form) {

                      $.ajax({
                            type: 'get',
                            url: 'loginuser.php',
                            data:{
                                username: $("#login_email").val(), pass: $("#login_password").val()
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                //alert(data);

                            }
                        });
                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use submitHandler to process something and then using the default submit.

```
$(".selector").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other things for a valid form
    form.submit();
  }
});
```